# How to register every click inside a div using prototype's observe

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I am trying to create a simple application that needs to hide and show div content on click. It fine except for the fact that any time I click on a span or the list, the div doesn't observe a click. What is the best way to observe all the clicks within this div?

```
 <div data-hour="16" data-minute="0" data-duration="1" class="even">
          <span class="title" >block:</span> <span>4:00PM</span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>item 1</li>
                    <li>item 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


$$('#contents >  div').each(function(item) {
        item.observe('click', respondToClick);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're catching and suppressing the clicks via handlers on the span or list, your code above should be working, and it does here: http://jsbin.com/etuka3 (That `observe` code can be shortened, though, via `invoke`: http://jsbin.com/etuka3/2).

As I'm sure you know, most DOM events "bubble" up from an element to its parent element to *its* parent element, etc., unless the bubbling is cancelled by an event handler somewhere in the chain. For instance, in [this version](http://jsbin.com/etuka3/3) of the above, I hook `click` on the `li`s and prevent the event reaching the `div`:

```
$$('#contents > div li').invoke('observe', 'click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevents the event from bubbling up to the ancestors
});
```

...which means clicking an `li`, the `div` doesn't see the click. But you have to do that on purpose, just hooking an event on a child element does *not* prevent bubbling, as you can see in [this example](http://jsbin.com/etuka3/4):

```
$$('#contents > div li').invoke('observe', 'click', function(event) {
    display("list item clicked");
});
```

Now when I click an `li`, we can see that the `li`'s handler gets triggered, and then (because I didn't stop bubbling), the `div`'s handler gets triggered.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The problem was that var element = event.element(); returns different elements depending on the element that was clicked on. I had failed to compensate and adjust for the element.

Comment: @maleki: Ah! Yes, with the event handler, Prototype ensures that `this` references the element you hooked the event on, and that `element.element()` (or `element.findElement()` with no arguments) returns the actual element that was clicked, which might be the same one or a descendant.